# Where should I put a question about captive portals?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

Where should I make a post about setting up a captive portal on a router I just obtained? It's not a fancy one that supports it by default. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming it's a home router, right?

If so, then you should use http://superuser.com

From their FAQ:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - *personal and home computer networking*[emphasis mine]

It appears to be on-topic, and the users are fairly open to variation, and are not extremely quick to barrage with downvotes or closevotes as Serverfault may do.

Comment: However, one got closed for off-topic on a [similar subject](http://superuser.com/questions/228705/custom-firmware-for-asus-wl-520g). I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: @boj That looks like the best site. There's nothing better. Good luck.

Comment: @boj Any success there?

Comment: @boj it was closed because what x works with y are considered as poll quesions and don't last long

Answer (score 3):

for problems related to computer hardware and networking, [super user](https://superuser.com/) is preferred.

Also have a look at [all other sites of stack exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Maybe you could find a relevant one